# How to compare two objects in dataframe series

Tags: java, python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
  colA colB
0    1    A
1    1    B
2    2    C
3    2    D
```

and I want to compare objects in colA and output rows if object < object in next row. I can do it in java like this

```
for(int i=0;i<df[0];i++){
    if(df[i][0]<df[i+1][0]){
         for(int j=0;j<df[1];j++){
             System.out.print(df[i][j]);
         }
    }
}
```

what I want is the row which colA[i]

```
 colA colB
    1    B
```

but I do not know how to do it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the following approach:

```
In [85]: df[df.colA.diff(-1).lt(0)]
Out[85]:
   colA colB
1     1    B
```

[Series.diff(-1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) returns a difference between current and next values:

```
In [10]: df.colA.diff(-1)
Out[10]:
0    0.0
1   -1.0
2    0.0
3    NaN
Name: colA, dtype: float64
```

`.diff()` returns a difference between previous and current values:

```
In [9]: df.colA.diff()
Out[9]:
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
Name: colA, dtype: float64
```

[lt(Val)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) - is `less than Val`:

```
In [13]: df.colA.lt(2)
Out[13]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: colA, dtype: bool
```

which is the same as:

```
In [14]: df.colA < 2
Out[14]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: colA, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already groupdf by the colA and sorted values by colA and colB. I just want to output rows which colA[i]<colA[i+1], not to judge if it is duplicated.

Comment: @gyoutoujyo, can you post your desired (output) data set?

Comment: I just compare the objects in colA one to next one, if object is smaller than the next one, I want to output the row which object in.

Comment: @gyoutoujyo, my answer does exactly that - isn't it?

Comment: thank you, python is quiet different from java.I think it needs a for loop.

Comment: The real power of Pandas is vectorized functions/methods which allow us to replace slow loops

Comment: another question is could you explain the parameter in diff() and lt(). I have tried parameter in lt() could be anything.

Comment: @gyoutoujyo, i've added some explanations

Comment: thx bro, really easy to understand. If you write the pandas doc, it will be easier to understand.